# AES decryption using pycrypto

Tags: aes, pycrypto

As a self study exercise, I'm trying to learn how to use some of the pycrypto library. I need to decrypt a ciphertext string in CBC_MODE using AES. I the ciphertext, key, and IV are all given. Here is the code that I have written:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

mode = AES.MODE_CBC
key = "a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1"
ciphertext = "a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1";

iv = ciphertext[:32] 
ciphertext = ciphertext[32:] 
decryptor = AES.new(key, mode, iv)
plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)
print plaintext
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long

I know that the IV string is 32 hex characters, and therefore 16 bytes. I think that this might be a typing problem, but I don't know how to correct it. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings contain only hex characters, but they are still plain strings, so every character counts.

So your IV string is 32 byte long as you sliced it out from `ciphertext`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're right and it is down to typing. Try one of these:

iv = binascii.unhexlify(ciphertext[:32])

or

iv = long(ciphertext[:32], 16)

Answer (score 0):

Tell the computer you are dealing with hex. It is treating it as a string. 
iv = iv.decode('hex');

Comment: It would help to explain **how** to "tell the computer" he is using hex.